# Automatic Stopwatch with Raspberry PI

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, iot

I want to build a automatic stopwatch for dog agility.
It's not very accurate to start and stop time with a ordinary one.
I need a sensor on the first jump and another sensor on the last jump.
The first start time and the second stop time.
And then view time on a display or so.
I found this project that is alike what i want.
https://www.hackster.io/falafelsoftware/ir-break-beam-hot-wheels-car-speed-track-361455

The sensor used in this **Adafruit Breakbeam Sensor**
https://learn.adafruit.com/ir-breakbeam-sensors/overview?view=all
If i understand it correctly the range is only up to 50 cm.
A jumps width is normally 120 cm but it can be up to 140 cm.
So i need at least 120cm range.

I want to use a raspberry Pi and windows C#.
I have experience with c# and visual studio but this will be my first IOT project.

I am very thankful for any help and tips to build this. 
Specially tips on a sensor that will work for me.

Comment: why the arduino tag?

Comment: The sensor work for arduino to, and i can get one if its necessary

Comment: I understand. Not a solution to your problem, but if you want an easy to build IOT device I would recomand looking into particles photon: https://www.particle.io/

Comment: The safety sensors used on garage doors should have the range you need. They are the same principle as the sensor you are looking at, but higher power. Here is [an example](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Chamberlain-Garage-Door-Opener-Replacement-Safety-Sensors-2-Pack-801CB/100651226)